# Can't create facebook album via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't create a Facebook album via graph api. Now, it always throws a error

> (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

I don't know why. I'm sure I have the correct access token (it is a valid, it does not expire). I have the same error in php & javascript.

My example code in js:

```
FB.api('/me/albums', 'post', {
            access_token: access_token, // it is a valid
            name: 'test album 1',
            message: 'test album 1'
        }, function(res) {

            console.log(res); // throw a error "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"
        });
```

**Does Facebook have some bugs or I missed something?**

**Edit:** I found the correct answer from https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/680991411993635/:

> Even though you are using a Page Access Token, you need the
>   **user_photos** permission in order to create a Photo Album as the Page.

Comment: No.. no bug... The error you get says it all. You do not have permissions to perform the action.

Comment: What permissions have you requested from your users?

Comment: @Lix my requested permissions are "manage_pages,publish_actions".  in my above code, i believe the "publish_actions" permission is enough

Comment: You can choose to believe that if you want... But that won't change the error message you are getting. You need `publish_stream`. An album is not an `action`.

Comment: @Lix in new facebook api, `publish_actions` replaces `publish_stream`. read more [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-publish]

Comment: Are you using the new version of the API?

Comment: @Lix of course, i use javascript sdk:   `$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function() {
FB.init({appId: xxxxxxxxx,version: 'v2.0'});
});`

Comment: publish_stream was already deprecated in v1 of the api afaik. it definitely works with publish_actions.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Thanks for submitting the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1505120126366435/

Comment: user_photos permision - that's it! The API reference for Album is lacking, it only mentions publish_actions. Wasted so much time...

Answer (score 0):

1. Facebook **does** have *some* bugs...don't we all?
2. You actually did miss something - you need the correct permissions.

In order to create an album, you'll need to request the [`publish_actions` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/) from your users. This permission allows your application to publish stories to the users feed including new albums.

Comment: Is there a way to check permissions set for the access token created?  I am getting this error and everything I know says that I have set the correct permissions.  I still can't upload.